# Magmi CLI does not find class 'Mage'

Tags: magmi, exception, cli

I have installed the Magmi into the magmi folder and I got it to work.
But somehow, it does not work anymore. I only get this exception:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Mage' not found in /var/www/c5shop/magmi/plugins    /extra/itemprocessors/groupprice/grouppriceprocessor.php on line 98
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /var/www/c5shop/magmi/cli/magmi.cli.php:0
PHP   2. Magmi_Engine->run() /var/www/c5shop/magmi/cli/magmi.cli.php:132
PHP   3. Magmi_ProductImportEngine->engineRun() /var/www/c5shop/magmi/inc/magmi_engine.php:485
PHP   4. Magmi_Engine->callPlugins() /var/www/c5shop/magmi/engines/magmi_productimportengine.php:1834
PHP   5. GrouppriceProcessor->processColumnList() /var/www/c5shop/magmi/inc/magmi_engine.php:323
```

I even copied the whole magento shop from the online site where it works, but I still keep getting this exception.

Comment: Does any other class get instantiated in this instance? e.g. `getModel('sales/order')`, `getModel('catalog/product')`, etc. work?

Answer (score 1):

group_price processor has been updated in [latest git commit](https://github.com/dweeves/magmi-git), removing all dependency on magento code. it should fix your problem.